# WebRTC - RTCDataChannel.readyState is not 'open'

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I'm trying to make a text chat, using WebRTC and data channels, but like the title suggests, it isn't working.

And the peer that's being contacted never has ondatachannel being called. Where did I screw up?

Code: https://hastebin.com/satoweyige.php

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Can you be more specific and mention the error/stacktrace you see in your post?

Comment: you have to specify more information about your code, and what exactly is the problem

Comment: We would prefer you to provide the code in the question itself using the JavaScript/HTML/CSS snippet button on top of editor instead of an external link.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use {RtpDataChannels: true} and burn the book you found that it. This is non-standard and known to lead to errors.